# How to stop (and not remove) a K8S cluster in autopilot mode

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

In order to save some money I wanted to stop a K8S cluster in GKE. My cluster is in autopilot mode and thus I don't have access to the nodes pool.

I have scale down all my pods to 0, but there is still 2 nodes in the cluster and I suppose this is charged to my account.

Is there any way to stop all nodes of a GKE cluster in Autopilot mode ?

Comment: Not possible, but you can try filing it as a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).